# how to do findOne for _id with spring data?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am using modgodb and spring-data, I am trying to execute `findOne(id)`, I have mapped id as String in my model, but in mongoDB `_id` is an `ObjectId`, when I execute findOne, it doesn't find the register.

Model:

```
public class Article {

    @Id
    public String id;
```

I am trying to do this:

```
    Article article = articleRepository.findOne(id);
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code you posted, and the behavior you describe (it is supposed to be an objectId). must be something else. Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching on collection `articles` collection while the collections was `article`. Specify collection is the key

```
@Document(collection="articles")
public class Article {

    @Id
    public String id;
```